# Is there a generally accepted way to handle my exceptions in a WPF/PRISM app?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm trying to redo an existing app of mine using PRISM to get at a more manageable app construction.

My app throws, of course, exceptions here and there, now handled in a custom handler.
I want to do it the Prism way.

I see two options:

1. '.Publish()' the error data from the catch-block with the IEventAggregator and subscribe to the event in an error-handling Prism Module (which I could then also use in other apps). In the module I would subscribe to the event and do the handling with a DialogService registered as a singleton.
2. Run that DialogService (show a Dialog) directly from the catch-block.

Which is the best (or only) way?

Comment: Neither. Keep your custom global handler and make sure to catch exceptions where they happen whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Prism Way" to handle exceptions.  The framework says nothing about them.   Exceptions can occur in situations where you would never want the user to know about them.  It depends on the nature of the exception.  Certainly, you do not want a dialog for every exception that occurs in your app.

In some cases, it is enough merely to log the exception.  If you are injecting some sort of event logging interface with Prism, then you should be able to do that no problem.  If you are NOT injecting an event log interface, start, doing it.

If the exception is important enough to notify the user, it is probably simpler to put the dialog right where the error occurs. That's assuming you are talking about a simple user alert and nothing more.

Only use IEventAggregator when other distinct components of your application need to know about what happened and your code (the part catching the exception) might not even know about them or how to notify them).  That is where IEventAggregator works best.

One thing about Prism's dialog service:  It is useful but it there is definitely some work to set up a dialog. If you are using any sort of UI toolkit that provides utility dialog functions for simple Alert/Prompt dialogs (as I fortunately am), I suggest using those instead.  Prism's dialogs shine better when you need complicated information returned.